# Displaying Facebook info of logged out user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Creating a Rails app that interacts heavily with Facebook. I want to users to be able to look at profiles of other users and see information on those users that has been pulled in from Facebook.

I'm using the omniauth-facebook and koala gems. I followed Ryan Bates' Railscasts on Facebook authentication and Facebook Graph API to get where I'm at.

I would prefer not to have to store a user's Facebook info in my database, but that seems to be the only way of doing it, because otherwise, when I try to view the profile page of another user who may have logged out, I get: "Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError in Profiles#show"
`type: OAuthException, code: 190, error_subcode: 467, message: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. [HTTP 400]`.

Is there a way to bring in this data from Facebook, even if that user has logged out?

Here's the necessary code:

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError
    logger.info e.to_s
    nil
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to feed_path
end

def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

profiles_helper.rb:

```
module ProfilesHelper
  def facebook_profile_info
    @user.facebook.get_object("#{@user.uid}",fields:'gender, locale, bio, birthday,
               picture, relationship_status')   
  end
end
```

Also, if you have suggestions on better ways to accomplish these tasks than the trajectory I'm headed in, I welcome your suggestions.

Comment: how did you make out with this? i get that error regardless when I make a call to facebook. in my user model, i have a method that is trying to do `facebook.get_connection("me", "friends")`. calling it in the view for that user gives me that error